# Android: Send Message from activity without "MessageIntent"

Tags: android, sms, message

I am using this code

```
   Intent intentsms = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "sms:" + "" ) );
    intentsms.putExtra( "sms_body", "Test text..." );
    startActivity( intentsms );
```

but this is open android message activity . But i dont want this .I want to send message dirctyly form my phone without click on Send Button

Thanks in advance

Comment: this not deserve +1 ... asked so many times google: android send sms without Intent ... this question shows only laziness of asker

Comment: I have searched so many time may be there is problem in my R&D . if you have  a solution  then plz give me the link... And Tanks if you dnt like this then you can down vote me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are welcome to send SMS messages directly [via `SmsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html), if your app holds the `SEND_SMS` permission.

```
  public void sendTheMessage(String message, String phoneNumber) {
      SmsManager
        .getDefault()
        .sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,
                         message,
                         null, null);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks it is working ... can i ask one more question from you